# Copy / Paster with terminal on MAC computer

Tags: macos

Please i dont know how to sue mac computers i'm trying to copy a folder into the hard drive but when i do the commande  cp -r [source] [destination] i get error no such file or directory exis, i cheked the path's and they are coorect ( i even tryed wit hthe drag and drop opttion into the terminal to avoid the wrong path errors, i check the permession on the folder as well and i have read/ write as well, also please note that when i try to copy into to hard drive directly i dont find the paste option at all when i click wit hthe righ on the mouse,

doesany one have any idea ?? why this happens ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it probably belongs on Ask Different Stack Exchange site.